# How to remove trailing </li> tags from wp_nav_menu walker

Tags: html, wordpress

I trying to migrate my website to Word press and I am stuck with a problem that when I use the example given by RCV ( [Wordpress change header navigation list items to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159486/wordpress-change-header-navigation-list-items-to-div) ) I get trailing `</li>` tags and I can't figure out how to remove them, this is the output I get.

```
<div class="top-left home">
    <div class="frame1">
        <a href="index.html"><span class="click"></span></a>
    </div></li>
    <div class="frame2"><h1 class="fittext1">Text<br/>Text<br/>Text</h1></div></li>
    <div class="frame3"><a href="Photo-price/index.html"><span class="click"></span></a>
        <h3 class="fittext3 bottomfull">text<span class="rightfull">></span></h3>
    </div></li>
</div>
```

any help would be most appreciated

Comment: have you used same code provided there ? or done some changes?

Comment: I used the same function file but made changes to my wp_nav_meu()

Comment: pl provide your changed code

Comment: these are some of the changes i have tried <?PHP
wp_nav_menu(
    array (
        'menu' => 'top-left home',
        'container' => 'div', // parent container 
        'depth' => 1,
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s', // removes ul
    'walker' => new Description_Walker // custom walker to replace li with div
    )
);
?>

Comment: change is simple, you just removed container id and even applying your code, it's working here

Comment: when I use the code as is the output is as follows '<div id="my_nav" class="menu-top-left-home-container">
 <div id='menu-item-38'  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a ></a></div></li>
 <div id='menu-item-36'  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a ></a></div></li>
 <div id='menu-item-37'  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a ></a></div></li>
</div>' do you have the link to where the code is actually working so that I can compare where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the trailing li tag because you've added the start_el method to your custom walker but you haven't added the end_el so it's using the default. Add the following to your custom walker class.

```
function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= "</div>\n";
}
```

You will then need to remove the closing div tag from your start_el. Alternatively you could set end_el to $output .= ""; but this isn't recommended.